# PDF.js with Angular 4 - buttons not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pdf.js, pdf-viewer

Actually, I'm developing a pdf viewer application in Angular 4 using Mozilla's PDF.js. [click](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js). I have taken PDF.js and pdf.worker.js files from github and pasted them into assets folder.

My index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html dir="ltr" mozdisallowselectionprint moznomarginboxes lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PDFViewerApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/CSS/viewer.css"> 
  <link rel="resource" type="application/l10n" href="../assets/CSS/locale/locale.properties">
</head>
<body tabindex="1" class="loadingInProgress">
   <script src="../assets/PDFJSFiles/pdf.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/PDFJSFiles/pdf.worker.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/PDFJSFiles/text_layer_builder.js">
</script>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

My Pdfviewer-component.html

```html
  <div class="split left">
      <h2> DQL </h2>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="100">{{dql}}</textarea>
      <button (click) = "fireDql()"> FIRE </button>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <table style="width:100%">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Object ID</th>
            <th>PDF link</th>
            <tr *ngFor="let row of list">
                <td>{{row.content.properties.object_name}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.content.properties.r_object_id}}</td>
                  <td><button (click)="viewPdf(row.content.properties.r_object_id)" >PDF</button></td>
            </tr>
      </table> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="split right" >
    <div id="outerContainer">

      <div id="sidebarContainer">
        <div id="toolbarSidebar">
          <div class="splitToolbarButton toggled">
            <button id="viewThumbnail" class="toolbarButton toggled" title="Show Thumbnails" tabindex="2" data-l10n-id="thumbs">
               <span data-l10n-id="thumbs_label">Thumbnails</span>
            </button>
            <button id="viewOutline" class="toolbarButton" title="Show Document Outline (double-click to expand/collapse all items)" tabindex="3" data-l10n-id="document_outline">
               <span data-l10n-id="document_outline_label">Document Outline</span>
            </button>
            <button id="viewAttachments" class="toolbarButton" title="Show Attachments" tabindex="4" data-l10n-id="attachments">
               <span data-l10n-id="attachments_label">Attachments</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebarContent">
          <div id="thumbnailView">
          </div>
          <div id="outlineView" class="hidden">
          </div>
          <div id="attachmentsView" class="hidden">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  <!-- sidebarContainer -->

      <div id="mainContainer">
        <div class="findbar hidden doorHanger" id="findbar">
          <div id="findbarInputContainer">
            <input id="findInput" class="toolbarField" title="Find" placeholder="Find in document…" tabindex="91" data-l10n-id="find_input">
            <div class="splitToolbarButton">
              <button id="findPrevious" class="toolbarButton findPrevious" title="Find the previous occurrence of the phrase" tabindex="92" data-l10n-id="find_previous">
                <span data-l10n-id="find_previous_label">Previous</span>
              </button>
              <div class="splitToolbarButtonSeparator"></div>
              <button id="findNext" class="toolbarButton findNext" title="Find the next occurrence of the phrase" tabindex="93" data-l10n-id="find_next">
                <span data-l10n-id="find_next_label">Next</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="findbarOptionsContainer">
            <input type="checkbox" id="findHighlightAll" class="toolbarField" tabindex="94">
            <label for="findHighlightAll" class="toolbarLabel" data-l10n-id="find_highlight">Highlight all</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="findMatchCase" class="toolbarField" tabindex="95">
            <label for="findMatchCase" class="toolbarLabel" data-l10n-id="find_match_case_label">Match case</label>
            <span id="findResultsCount" class="toolbarLabel hidden"></span>
          </div>

          <div id="findbarMessageContainer">
            <span id="findMsg" class="toolbarLabel"></span>
          </div>
        </div>  <!-- findbar -->

        <div id="secondaryToolbar" class="secondaryToolbar hidden doorHangerRight">
          <div id="secondaryToolbarButtonContainer">
            <button id="secondaryPresentationMode" class="secondaryToolbarButton presentationMode visibleLargeView" title="Switch to Presentation Mode" tabindex="51" data-l10n-id="presentation_mode">
              <span data-l10n-id="presentation_mode_label">Presentation Mode</span>
            </button>

            <button id="secondaryOpenFile" class="secondaryToolbarButton openFile visibleLargeView" title="Open File" tabindex="52" data-l10n-id="open_file">
              <span data-l10n-id="open_file_label">Open</span>
            </button>

            <button id="secondaryPrint" class="secondaryToolbarButton print visibleMediumView" title="Print" tabindex="53" data-l10n-id="print">
              <span data-l10n-id="print_label">Print</span>
            </button>

            <button id="secondaryDownload" class="secondaryToolbarButton download visibleMediumView" title="Download" tabindex="54" data-l10n-id="download">
              <span data-l10n-id="download_label">Download</span>
            </button>

            <a href="#" id="secondaryViewBookmark" class="secondaryToolbarButton bookmark visibleSmallView" title="Current view (copy or open in new window)" tabindex="55" data-l10n-id="bookmark">
              <span data-l10n-id="bookmark_label">Current View</span>
            </a>

            <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator visibleLargeView"></div>

            <button id="firstPage" class="secondaryToolbarButton firstPage" title="Go to First Page" tabindex="56" data-l10n-id="first_page">
              <span data-l10n-id="first_page_label">Go to First Page</span>
            </button>
            <button id="lastPage" class="secondaryToolbarButton lastPage" title="Go to Last Page" tabindex="57" data-l10n-id="last_page">
              <span data-l10n-id="last_page_label">Go to Last Page</span>
            </button>

            <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator"></div>

            <button id="pageRotateCw" class="secondaryToolbarButton rotateCw" title="Rotate Clockwise" tabindex="58" data-l10n-id="page_rotate_cw">
              <span data-l10n-id="page_rotate_cw_label">Rotate Clockwise</span>
            </button>
            <button id="pageRotateCcw" class="secondaryToolbarButton rotateCcw" title="Rotate Counterclockwise" tabindex="59" data-l10n-id="page_rotate_ccw">
              <span data-l10n-id="page_rotate_ccw_label">Rotate Counterclockwise</span>
            </button>

            <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator"></div>

            <button id="cursorSelectTool" class="secondaryToolbarButton selectTool toggled" title="Enable Text Selection Tool" tabindex="60" data-l10n-id="cursor_text_select_tool">
              <span data-l10n-id="cursor_text_select_tool_label">Text Selection Tool</span>
            </button>
            <button id="cursorHandTool" class="secondaryToolbarButton handTool" title="Enable Hand Tool" tabindex="61" data-l10n-id="cursor_hand_tool">
              <span data-l10n-id="cursor_hand_tool_label">Hand Tool</span>
            </button>

            <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator"></div>

            <button id="documentProperties" class="secondaryToolbarButton documentProperties" title="Document Properties…" tabindex="62" data-l10n-id="document_properties">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_label">Document Properties…</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>  <!-- secondaryToolbar -->

        <div class="toolbar">
          <div id="toolbarContainer">
            <div id="toolbarViewer">
              <div id="toolbarViewerLeft">
                <button id="sidebarToggle" class="toolbarButton" title="Toggle Sidebar" tabindex="11" data-l10n-id="toggle_sidebar">
                  <span data-l10n-id="toggle_sidebar_label">Toggle Sidebar</span>
                </button>
                <div class="toolbarButtonSpacer"></div>
                <button id="viewFind" class="toolbarButton" title="Find in Document" tabindex="12" data-l10n-id="findbar">
                  <span data-l10n-id="findbar_label">Find</span>
                </button>
                <div class="splitToolbarButton hiddenSmallView">
                  <button class="toolbarButton pageUp" title="Previous Page" id="previous" (click)="changePagePrevious()" tabindex="13" data-l10n-id="previous">
                    <span data-l10n-id="previous_label">Previous</span>
                  </button>
                  <div class="splitToolbarButtonSeparator"></div>
                  <button class="toolbarButton pageDown" title="Next Page" id="next" (click)="changePageNext()" tabindex="14" data-l10n-id="next">
                    <span data-l10n-id="next_label">Next</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <input type="number" id="pageNumber" class="toolbarField pageNumber" title="Page" [value]="pageNumber" size="4" min="1" tabindex="15" data-l10n-id="page">
                <span id="numPages" class="toolbarLabel">of {{totalPages}}</span>
              </div>
              <div id="toolbarViewerRight">
                <button id="presentationMode" class="toolbarButton presentationMode hiddenLargeView" title="Switch to Presentation Mode" tabindex="31" data-l10n-id="presentation_mode">
                  <span data-l10n-id="presentation_mode_label">Presentation Mode</span>
                </button>

                <button id="openFile" class="toolbarButton openFile hiddenLargeView" title="Open File" tabindex="32" data-l10n-id="open_file">
                  <span data-l10n-id="open_file_label">Open</span>
                </button>

                <button id="print" class="toolbarButton print hiddenMediumView" (click)="print()" title="Print" tabindex="33" data-l10n-id="print">
                  <span data-l10n-id="print_label">Print</span>
                </button>

                <button id="download" class="toolbarButton download hiddenMediumView" title="Download" tabindex="34" data-l10n-id="download">
                  <span data-l10n-id="download_label">Download</span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" id="viewBookmark" class="toolbarButton bookmark hiddenSmallView" title="Current view (copy or open in new window)" tabindex="35" data-l10n-id="bookmark">
                  <span data-l10n-id="bookmark_label">Current View</span>
                </a>

                <div class="verticalToolbarSeparator hiddenSmallView"></div>

                <button id="secondaryToolbarToggle" class="toolbarButton" title="Tools" tabindex="36" data-l10n-id="tools">
                  <span data-l10n-id="tools_label">Tools</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div id="toolbarViewerMiddle">
                <div class="splitToolbarButton">
                  <button id="zoomOut" class="toolbarButton zoomOut" title="Zoom Out" tabindex="21" data-l10n-id="zoom_out">
                    <span data-l10n-id="zoom_out_label">Zoom Out</span>
                  </button>
                  <div class="splitToolbarButtonSeparator"></div>
                  <button id="zoomIn" class="toolbarButton zoomIn" title="Zoom In" tabindex="22" data-l10n-id="zoom_in">
                    <span data-l10n-id="zoom_in_label">Zoom In</span>
                   </button>
                </div>
                <span id="scaleSelectContainer" class="dropdownToolbarButton">
                  <select id="scaleSelect" title="Zoom" tabindex="23" data-l10n-id="zoom">
                    <option id="pageAutoOption" title="" value="auto" selected="selected" data-l10n-id="page_scale_auto">Automatic Zoom</option>
                    <option id="pageActualOption" title="" value="page-actual" data-l10n-id="page_scale_actual">Actual Size</option>
                    <option id="pageFitOption" title="" value="page-fit" data-l10n-id="page_scale_fit">Page Fit</option>
                    <option id="pageWidthOption" title="" value="page-width" data-l10n-id="page_scale_width">Page Width</option>
                    <option id="customScaleOption" title="" value="custom" disabled="disabled" hidden="true"></option>
                    <option title="" value="0.5" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 50 }'>50%</option>
                    <option title="" value="0.75" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 75 }'>75%</option>
                    <option title="" value="1" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 100 }'>100%</option>
                    <option title="" value="1.25" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 125 }'>125%</option>
                    <option title="" value="1.5" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 150 }'>150%</option>
                    <option title="" value="2" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 200 }'>200%</option>
                    <option title="" value="3" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 300 }'>300%</option>
                    <option title="" value="4" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 400 }'>400%</option>
                  </select>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="loadingBar">
              <div class="progress">
                <div class="glimmer">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <menu type="context" id="viewerContextMenu">
          <menuitem id="contextFirstPage" label="First Page"
                    data-l10n-id="first_page"></menuitem>
          <menuitem id="contextLastPage" label="Last Page"
                    data-l10n-id="last_page"></menuitem>
          <menuitem id="contextPageRotateCw" label="Rotate Clockwise"
                    data-l10n-id="page_rotate_cw"></menuitem>
          <menuitem id="contextPageRotateCcw" label="Rotate Counter-Clockwise"
                    data-l10n-id="page_rotate_ccw"></menuitem>
        </menu>
        <!--Ravi test
         <div id="viewerContainer" tabindex="0">
          <div id="viewer" class="pdfViewer"></div>
        </div>
         -->
      <div class="container">
          <div id="page_1"></div>
          <canvas id="main-canvas" width="1000"></canvas>
        </div>
       
        <div id="errorWrapper" hidden='true'>
          <div id="errorMessageLeft">
            <span id="errorMessage"></span>
            <button id="errorShowMore" data-l10n-id="error_more_info">
              More Information
            </button>
            <button id="errorShowLess" data-l10n-id="error_less_info" hidden='true'>
              Less Information
            </button>
          </div>
          <div id="errorMessageRight">
            <button id="errorClose" data-l10n-id="error_close">
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="clearBoth"></div>
          <textarea id="errorMoreInfo" hidden='true' readonly="readonly"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- mainContainer -->

      <div id="overlayContainer" class="hidden">
        <div id="passwordOverlay" class="container hidden">
          <div class="dialog">
            <div class="row">
              <p id="passwordText" data-l10n-id="password_label">Enter the password to open this PDF file:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <input type="password" id="password" class="toolbarField">
            </div>
            <div class="buttonRow">
              <button id="passwordCancel" class="overlayButton"><span data-l10n-id="password_cancel">Cancel</span></button>
              <button id="passwordSubmit" class="overlayButton"><span data-l10n-id="password_ok">OK</span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="documentPropertiesOverlay" class="container hidden">
          <div class="dialog">
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_file_name">File name:</span> <p id="fileNameField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_file_size">File size:</span> <p id="fileSizeField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_title">Title:</span> <p id="titleField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_author">Author:</span> <p id="authorField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_subject">Subject:</span> <p id="subjectField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_keywords">Keywords:</span> <p id="keywordsField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_creation_date">Creation Date:</span> <p id="creationDateField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_modification_date">Modification Date:</span> <p id="modificationDateField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_creator">Creator:</span> <p id="creatorField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_producer">PDF Producer:</span> <p id="producerField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_version">PDF Version:</span> <p id="versionField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_page_count">Page Count:</span> <p id="pageCountField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="buttonRow">
              <button id="documentPropertiesClose" class="overlayButton"><span data-l10n-id="document_properties_close">Close</span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="printServiceOverlay" class="container hidden">
          <div class="dialog">
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="print_progress_message">Preparing document for printing…</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
              <span data-l10n-id="print_progress_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "progress": 0 }' class="relative-progress">0%</span>
            </div>
            <div class="buttonRow">
              <button id="printCancel" class="overlayButton"><span data-l10n-id="print_progress_close">Cancel</span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  <!-- overlayContainer -->

    </div> <!-- outerContainer -->
    <div id="printContainer"></div>
  </div>


<!-- 
        <span>Page {{pageNumber}} of {{totalPages}}</span>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="page_1"></div>
            <canvas id="main-canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div>
  <button (click)="changePagePrevious()">Previous </button>
  <button (click)="changePageNext()">Next </button>
</div>
-->
```

**My Question is:**
**I'm able to view the PDF inside the viewer. But there are no operation on that pdf like print, zoom in, zoom out, previous page, next page, thumbnails, rotate etc.
How do I provide functionality for all the operations?**

Here is the screenshot of the PDFViewer:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can provide those functionality. They are part of the adobe plugin which is installed in the browser. As you can see, you have the scrollbar, and probably you cna navigate with arrow keys

Comment: Hi @Yuri, Actually I'm developing that viewer in Angular 4 and I'm not using any plug-in. So I think there is no way of getting functionality by default. I've to provide functionality for UI components right. I don't know to how to implement that functionalities like rotation, print, pagenext, pagePrevious etc. That's why I've raised a question here .

Comment: @RaviKumarB were you able to successfully integrate pdfjs in angular? Actually  i have a similar required where i need to reskin entire pdfjs and use custom skin. Could you please provide your inputs.